# url_key not updated

Tags: magento-2.1, url, url-rewrite

I installed **Magento 2.1.3 enterprise edition**. I created new category and a new product. It shows frontend correctly with given **url_key** under SEO tab. Now I need to change the **url_key**. When I change, It doesn't reflect in frontend, old **url_key** is used to display the product. But it displays updated value in back-end.

**NOTE**

I tried to update attributes in catalog grid actions option. But nothing happen.

**UPDATE**

If I change **url_key** and save manually, **url_rewrite** table creates the new url with 301 permanent redirection. But when I update **url_key** via script it's not working.

So please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This solve for CE, it can doesn't approach for EE.

If you modify url_key attribute in your own script directly (without saving product), you need to add code for the rewrite creating manually.

Magento add this functionality after saving product in observer:

> Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer\ProductProcessUrlRewriteSavingObserver

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){        
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

    if ($product->dataHasChangedFor('url_key')
        || $product->getIsChangedCategories()
        || $product->getIsChangedWebsites()
        || $product->dataHasChangedFor('visibility')
    ) {
        $this->urlPersist->deleteByData([
            UrlRewrite::ENTITY_ID => $product->getId(),
            UrlRewrite::ENTITY_TYPE => ProductUrlRewriteGenerator::ENTITY_TYPE,
            UrlRewrite::REDIRECT_TYPE => 0,
            UrlRewrite::STORE_ID => $product->getStoreId()
        ]);

        if ($product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()) {
            $this->urlPersist->replace($this->productUrlRewriteGenerator->generate($product));
        }
    }
}
```

You should add this code to your own script with some changes, of course.

Comment: I saved product manually with different url_key, but this also not updated in url_rewrite table.